# Register output parameter for calling stored procedure in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
create procedure sp_findMaxEmployee
    @maxID as varchar(10) OUTPUT
as
    SET @maxID = (SELECT MAX(e_ID) FROM Employee)
go
```

I try to register an output parameter like this:

```
public string generateID()
{
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_findMaxEmployee", connection);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@maxID";
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
            return cmd.Parameters["@maxID"].Value.ToString();
}
```

I tried to execute this procedure in SQL and it return right value, but when I execute project in debug mode, it shows me error:

> String[0]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Null value? Can you help me, thank you so much!

Comment: You didn't specify the size for the parameter.

Comment: E_ID is it a VARCHAR column ??

Comment: size of parameter is optional, I think. Yup! e_ID 's a varchar column

Comment: @BryantNguyen are the values actually numbers in a varchar column? I can't see how MAX() would work effectively on that? I'd change it to be an int (identity column), surely that would make much more sense?

Comment: @Tanner: I tried to execute it and it work properly!

Comment: Tanner You haven't used the OUTPUT parameter in your stored procedure thats why it works for you the way you are doing it and it isn't working for Bryant Nguyen.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `e_ID` is a `integer`, you can just perform a `SELECT` and `ExecuteScalar` to return a single value:

```
create procedure sp_findMaxEmployee
as
SELECT MAX(e_ID) FROM Employee
go
```

Then in code, something like:

```
public string generateID()
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
    cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_findMaxEmployee", connection);

    connection.Open();
    var maxId = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
    return maxId.ToString();
}
```

Finally, there's probably a deeper question as to why you are returning the last ID, hopefully it's not to get the next available ID, which you should let SQL do on your behalf by letting it auto-increment.

Comment: Thank you so much, Tanner! But I can this way, but I want to register an output parameter! :)

Comment: actually I doing an auto-increment with my own format as this: "EMP-0001" to EMP-n! This's a step to implement auto-increment algorithm! But thank you so much, Tanner!

Answer (score 0):

**Little Tweak for SP**

The Tweak is not necessary but it looks better this way :) and also please avoid using `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Use `usp_` instead.

```
create procedure usp_findMaxEmployee
@maxID as varchar(10) OUTPUT  
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @maxID =  MAX(e_ID) FROM Employee;
END
```

**Calling from Code**

```
public string generateID()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_findMaxEmployee", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // set up the parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@maxID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    // open connection and execute stored procedure
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // read output value from @maxID
    String maxID = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["@maxID"].Value);
    conn.Close();
    return maxID;
}
```

**Note**

Use the using block of Try/Catch/Finnaly blocks to close connection if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Can you explain why use "usp_" prefix instead of using "sp_". Because of I use it for an age :|

Comment: @BryantNguyen you shouldn't, Please read this [`Avoid using sp_ as a prefix for stored procedures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @BryantNguyen Glad to help you can accept the answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a .Size for your parameter.  Your stored procedure specifies an output of varchar(10), so you should set the param.Size = 10;

You need to specify that cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,  the default CommandType is CommandType.Text

Make those changes and your method works as you intended.